# TYPO3 Extbase: Cannot create empty instance of the class ...ObjectStorage

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have the following TYPO3 error at my project during `extbase extension creation`

```
Cannot create empty instance of the class
"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage" because it does not implement
the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\DomainObjectInterface.
```

I think it has to do with loading objects from another extension `rezepte`.

```
'rezepte' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:nebenwirkungen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_nebenwirkungen_domain_model_nebenwirkung.rezepte',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_rezepte_domain_model_rezept',
                            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_rezepte_domain_model_rezept.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ORDER BY tx_rezepte_domain_model_rezept.rezeptname',
            'MM' => 'tx_nebenwirkungen_nebenwirkung__mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 1,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was wrong:

I forgot to set the type of the object storage in the model file:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<>
```

has to be:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\EmP\Rezepte\Domain\Model\Rezept>
```